# Foot Pedal software for OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I needed to pick up a [foot pedal](http://www.altoedge.com/pedals/index.html) for my job, and while it's working with the prescribed software well enough, I'd really like to be able to put it to use in other applications as well (e.g. iTunes or Final Cut).  Unfortunately, however, the site only offers configuration software for Windows.  Is there a preference pane or configuration program available for OS X for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ControllerMate might be able to do it, presuming it's a USB HID device and not something strange: http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's tip is legit, I setup my Controllermate on a `Philips LFH2330` which has 4 buttons. By default they're ordered like the following image demonstrates...

[image: Philips LFH-2330 default button arrangement]

The configuration I enabled to map buttons 2 and 3 to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and button 1 to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to make the left half do Copy commands and the right Paste commands looks like this...

[image: Controller Mate configuration for Philips LFH-2330 Configurable USB Foot Control/Pedal]

I defined two keystrokes outputs used to capture the copy/paste keyboard commands. You record them like a macro of sorts by pressing the "Capture" button and the carrying out your keystrokes and then stopping the recording once finished.

[image: Keystrokes building block highlight.]